# Mysql: SUM() gives 4 times the value with multiple join and where conditions

Tags: mysql, otrs

I'm trying to generate a report from OTRS Ticket System. Here are the various tables in use:
*ticket_history*

```
+--------+-----------------+-----------+----------+---------------------+
| id     | history_type_id | ticket_id | state_id | change_time         |
+--------+-----------------+-----------+----------+---------------------+
| 302214 |               1 |     12748 |        1 | 2015-09-22 21:08:10 |
| 302215 |              38 |     12748 |        1 | 2015-09-22 21:08:10 |
| 303538 |              27 |     12748 |       12 | 2015-10-07 09:44:32 |
| 303539 |              15 |     12748 |       12 | 2015-10-07 09:44:32 |
| 303540 |              20 |     12748 |       12 | 2015-10-07 09:44:32 |
| 303541 |              28 |     12748 |       12 | 2015-10-07 09:44:32 |
*| 303542 |              27 |     12748 |        3 | 2015-10-07 09:45:58 |*
| 303543 |              18 |     12748 |        3 | 2015-10-07 09:45:58 |
| 303544 |              15 |     12748 |        3 | 2015-10-07 09:45:58 |
| 303545 |              20 |     12748 |        3 | 2015-10-07 09:45:58 |
| 303546 |              17 |     12748 |        3 | 2015-10-07 09:46:32 |
| 303547 |              25 |     12748 |        3 | 2015-10-07 09:46:32 |
| 303548 |              27 |     12748 |       12 | 2015-10-07 09:46:45 |
| 303549 |              15 |     12748 |       12 | 2015-10-07 09:46:45 |
*| 303550 |              27 |     12748 |        2 | 2015-10-07 09:47:43 |*
```

*ticket*

```
+-------+------------------+----------+
| id    | tn               | queue_id |
+-------+------------------+----------+
| 12748 | 2015092210000093 |        5 |
+-------+------------------+----------+
```

*time_accounting*

```
+------+-----------+-----------+---------------------+
| id   | ticket_id | time_unit | change_time         |
+------+-----------+-----------+---------------------+
| 3381 |     12748 |      1.00 | 2015-10-07 09:44:32 |
| 3382 |     12748 |      1.00 | 2015-10-07 09:45:58 |
| 3383 |     12748 |      0.25 | 2015-10-07 09:47:43 |
+------+-----------+-----------+---------------------+
```

*dynamic_field_value*

```
+--------+----------+-----------+------------+------------+-----------+
| id     | field_id | object_id | value_text | value_date | value_int |
+--------+----------+-----------+------------+------------+-----------+
| 108882 |       47 |     12748 | 3         | NULL       |      NULL |
| 109038 |       64 |     12748 | test       | NULL       |      NULL |
| 109040 |       98 |     12748 | --         | NULL       |      NULL |
| 109039 |       99 |     12748 | 0          | NULL       |      NULL |
```

My query:

```
select
ticket_history.ticket_id, 
CASE WHEN dynamic_field_value.field_id = 99 THEN dynamic_field_value.value_text else NULL END AS 'V1', 
CASE WHEN dynamic_field_value.field_id = 64 THEN dynamic_field_value.value_text else NULL END AS 'V2',
SUM(time_accounting.time_unit), 
max(ticket_history.change_time) 

from ticket_history 
left join time_accounting 
on ticket_history.ticket_id = time_accounting.ticket_id 
left join dynamic_field_value 
on ticket_history.ticket_id = dynamic_field_value.object_id 
AND dynamic_field_value.field_id IN (99,64) 

where ticket_history.ticket_id=12748 
AND ticket_history.history_type_id IN (1,27) 
AND ticket_history.state_id IN (2,3);
```

*The result I get:*

```
+-----------+------+------+--------------------------------+---------------------------------+
| ticket_id | V1   | V2   | SUM(time_accounting.time_unit) | max(ticket_history.change_time) |
+-----------+------+------+--------------------------------+---------------------------------+
|     12748 | NULL | test |                           9.00 | 2015-10-07 09:47:43             |
+-----------+------+------+--------------------------------+---------------------------------+
```

As you can see I get a sum which is 4 times the original time_unit value (4*2.25). I guess its because of 4 times join, that is happening because of two dynamic_field_value.value_text and the where condition is matched twice(* marked). How can I correct this problem to get the right sum? Please note, the tables are shortened to save sapce only for example and contains more rows in reality.

Comment: Can we see the sqlfiddle of same?

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: @ArunKrish expected result would be the sum of time_unit value from table time_accounting for the given object_id 12748, in this case 2.25.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use subquery for that time calculation

```
SELECT 
ticket_history.ticket_id,
CASE WHEN dynamic_field_value.field_id = 99 THEN dynamic_field_value.value_text else NULL END AS 'V1', 
CASE WHEN dynamic_field_value.field_id = 64 THEN dynamic_field_value.value_text else NULL END AS 'V2', 
(SELECT SUM(time_unit) FROM time_accounting WHERE ticket_id =ticket_history.ticket_id) AS time,
MAX(ticket_history.change_time) 

FROM ticket_history 
LEFT JOIN time_accounting on ticket_history.ticket_id = time_accounting.ticket_id 
LEFT JOIN dynamic_field_value on ticket_history.ticket_id = dynamic_field_value.object_id AND dynamic_field_value.field_id IN (99,64) 
WHERE ticket_history.ticket_id=12748 AND ticket_history.history_type_id IN (1,27) AND ticket_history.state_id IN (2,3)
```

And the output I got

```
ticket_id   V1      V2      time    max(ticket_history.change_time)     
  12748     NULL    test    2.25    2015-10-07 09:47:43
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have tested and it gives correct ouput. Well, but when there is more than one ticket_id,  this query doesn't work. For example:  `where ticket_history.ticket_id IN (12748,12783)`, I get only one row for id 12748. In reality it will be used for more than one id. May be I should have mentioned it in my question already. Anyway, if there is no other solution, I will accept it as answer.

Comment: then you add GROUP BY ticket_history.ticket_id at the end if you want for every row for a ticket_id

Answer (score 0):

if you delete the last table you will received the results you want,

table "dynamic_field_value" created cartesian since to each row you will received 2 results , actually since the first table give you 2 relevant rows  and the tired table also received two results you received 2^2=4

try this

```
select 
ticket_history.ticket_id, 
CASE WHEN dynamic_field_value.field_id = 99 THEN dynamic_field_value.value_text else NULL END AS 'V1', 
CASE WHEN dynamic_field_value.field_id = 64 THEN dynamic_field_value.value_text else NULL END AS 'V2', SUM(time_accounting.time_unit)/count(case when time_accounting.time_unit=0.25 then time_accounting.id end), 
max(ticket_history.change_time)

from ticket_history 
left join time_accounting on ticket_history.ticket_id = time_accounting.ticket_id 
left join dynamic_field_value on ticket_history.ticket_id = dynamic_field_value.object_id AND dynamic_field_value.field_id IN (99,64) 

where ticket_history.ticket_id=12748 AND ticket_history.history_type_id IN (1,27) AND ticket_history.state_id IN (2,3);
The
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. But I just can't delete a table and I need to get the value from that table too. And even if I don't do join with dynamic_field_value table, I get twice the value as expected because the where condition get matched twice.

Comment: divided the results in count(*), try the query i put in the answer

Comment: Well, currently I am dividing the sum to get correct result. The problem is, in production there are different situations arising and I have to manually correct everytime. Like this example here, where the condition is matching twice (combination of history_type_id and state_id), is a special case (when a ticket is closed twice). What I understand, I have to get the 'join' correctly and that the condition is considered once even if it is matched more than once, but I don't know how.

Comment: your right you need to fit the solution to each case, thats why you should avoid to use cartesian in your query, in your case try to add another condition on unique field like field_id in table dynamic_field_value